# Image is not opening in light box using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using pretty photo gallery. I have to open the thumbnail image in light box, but when I click on the thumbnail image it opens in a new window instead of the light box.

## Images are loading from a [json](/questions/tagged/json) file using [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax):

```
var article  = "";
$.each(data, function( index, value ) {
    article +="<article class='entry isotope-item "+value.pcat_slug+"'><a href='images/portfolio/"+value.pcat_slug+"/"+value.pimg_name+"' rel='prettyPhoto[pp_gal]' data-rel='prettyPhoto'><img class='img-responsive' data-original='images/portfolio/"+value.pcat_slug+"/"+value.pimg_name+"' alt='"+value.pcat_name+"' title='"+value.pcat_name+"' src='images/portfolio/"+value.pcat_slug+"/"+value.pimg_name+"' /><span class='magnifier'></span></a></article>";
    //li +="<li class='"+value.cat_slug+"'><img src='images/portfolio/logo/"+value.pcat_slug+"/"+value.pimg_name+"'/></li>";
});

$(".portfolio").empty();
$(".portfolio").append(article);
$(".portfolio").append("<div class='clear'></div>");
```

## Images will show in this div after loading from ajax:

```
<div class="portfolio"></div>
```

## I am using below code to open popup:

```
/*prettyPhoto*/ jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('a[data-gal]').each(function() { jQuery(this).attr('rel', jQuery(this).data('gal'));}); jQuery("a[data-rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({animationSpeed:'slow',theme:'light_square',slideshow:false,overlay_gallery: false,social_tools:false,deeplinking:false});
});
```

Comment: The problem lies that at document ready the prettyPhoto part is already loaded, so what you should do is on document ready first generate `.portfolio` and then run the prettyPhoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use window.load instead of document.ready. Please see below code.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
jQuery('a[data-gal]').each(function() { jQuery(this).attr('rel', jQuery(this).data('gal'));});
jQuery("a[data-rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({animationSpeed:'slow',theme:'light_square',slideshow:false,overlay_gallery: false,social_tools:false,deeplinking:false});
});
```